# gzip: stdin: Input/output error /bin/sh: line 1: /logfo/dynamo.log-20150317.gz: Permission denied

Tags: python

```
import subprocess
g_rep = 'zgrep i_d /logfo/dynam*'
f = open('fi.txt', "r")
for i in f:
        g_rep = 'zgrep ' + i + ' /logfo/dynam*'
        print g_rep
        k = subprocess.Popen(['zgrep ' + i + '/logfo/dynamo*'], shell=True)
        print k

g_rep = 'zgrep ' + i + ' /logfo/dynam*'
print g_rep
```

When I am executing the script i got the output as:

```
zgrep 211043369013

/logfo/dynam*
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xabe190>

zgrep 211043369013

/logfo/dynam*
```

but actual output should be.. `zgrep 211043369013 /logfo/dynam*`
please help me how to bring in single line

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure what you are trying to achieve but `i` will have a newline char so you see the output on different lines, you need to rstrip:

```
'zgrep ' + i.rstrip() + ' /logfo/dynam
```

You seem to be reassigning and not using some variables like your initial value for `g_rep`, I also think check_output might be more suitable passing a list of args without using `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess

with open('fi.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        g_rep = 'zgrep {} /logfo/dynam*'.format(i.rstrip())
        print g_rep
        k = subprocess.check_output(["zgrep",i.rstrip(),"/logfo/dynam*"])
        print k
```